# How to translate an English JSON array to another language

Tags: android, google-translation-api

I have a JSON array to translate in multiple languages. I've tried [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/translate-text) but it didn't help as you can only translate a single string.

The JSON:

```
[
      {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "title": "parihar",
        "type": "veg hotel",
        "area":"some place",
        "is_open":"open"
        "term":"some text"
      },
      {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 2,
        "title": "parihar2",
        "type": "veg hotel",
        "area":"some place",
        "is_open":"open"
        "term":"some text"
      }]
```

Comment: Why didn't the link help?

Comment: because there is a single string convert per request not full object